# Can a user connect to my web site using an Orkut account ? Like Facebook Connect but for Orkut

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can a user connect to my web site using an Orkut account ? Just like 
Google Friend Connect or Facebook, but with Orkut.

The idea is, the user goes to my web site, I have a "Connect using Orkut" button there, on click takes him to the Orkut login page, once s/he logins and grants access to my app, get's redirected to my web site with the Orkut ID as a parameter. The same procedure that works for Google Friend Connect and also Facebook Connect....

I haven't seen an example of this with Orkut. Can it be done ? Is there an Orkut Connect or similar ?

If there is one such example could you please give me a link to it ?
A sample in c# would be excellent, but I would be happy with a sample in any language.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Did you find if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Since Orkut uses Google Accounts, you can use either Google Accounts authentication or Google OpenId provider.