# It possible to integrate Orkut like using Oauth like Facebook and Twitter

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, dataoutputstream

As per information i have, Aouth provides very stander plateform for authentication for accessing thirdpary social networking website like Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn.

Is it possible to Orkut integration with Website for third party user in PHP. If yes so please Help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a user connect to my web site using an Orkut account ? Like Facebook Connect but for Orkut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600470/can-a-user-connect-to-my-web-site-using-an-orkut-account-like-facebook-connect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can use either Google Accounts authentication or Google OpenId provider.
And it turn possible login with any Google Account (orkut, youtube, buzz, gmail, etc).